# how to do CSS for below image box (not a shadow box)

Tags: css

Yesterday I came across the concept of shadow box, but my below image is not a shadow box, it's,
1. a simple div with 1px border.

```
div{
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
border: 1px solid black;
}
```

2. there is an extra thick layer of border across the right and bottom edge of box **but not equal** to the width of respective borders, hence below code is **not works** for me,

```
div{
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
border: 1px solid black;
border-bottom: 5px solid black;
border-right: 5px solid black;
}
```

[image]

Please suggest some CSS for such box. Thanks,

Comment: I'm thinking of creating a black box with same size but with 1px lower and more right than the original...

Comment: What is the problem you are facing with `box-shadow` ?

Comment: @gaurav, this is not a shadow box

Comment: you can do that with shadow box only

Comment: Yes, we all got that it is not a box-shadow. Is the purpose of that dark box just visual or does it involve some jQuery?

Comment: @SuperHornet Incorrect. See my answer.

Comment: @gaurav, just visual purpouse

Comment: Is a solution working in IE8+ OK for you? Or else which versions of IE do you have to support *pixel perfect*?

Comment: @FelipeAls, IE8+ is OK.

Comment: it's not duplicate, requirement is changed now and I'm not looking for shadow box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you better to copy the below code and check once, i think it better works what you like your output.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

    <style>
        body {
            text-align:center;
        }
        * {
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
            border:0;
        }
        a {
            text-decoration:none;
            outline:none;
        }
        .container {
            margin:10px auto;
            width:960px;
        }
        .black {
            background:#000;
            width:200px;
            height:100px;
            border-radius: 0 4px 0 4px;
            bottom: -4px;
            height: 98px;
            position: absolute;
            right: -4px;
            width: 200px;
            z-index: -1;
        }
        .white {
            border:1px solid #000;
            background:#fff;
            width:200px;
            height:100px;
            position:relative;
        }
    </style>
</head>


<body>

    <div class="container">
    <div class="white">
        <div class="black">
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a tricky solution ( no CSS3, supported by all browsers ):

HTML

```
<div id="white_box"></div>
<div id="black_box"></div>
```

CSS

```
#white_box {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: #FFF;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    z-index: 5;
}
#black_box {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #000;
    position: absolute;
    top: 23px;
    left: 23px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7AE5p/)

Update: with 1 DIV only : [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7AE5p/2/)

Comment: using 2 DIV is a problem?

Comment: no, not a issue and I thought this can't achieve by single div

Comment: added a solution with 1 DIV , even more tricky.

Comment: but hard to manage top/left/z-index with actual implementation

Comment: could you please provide solution with 1 DIV?

Comment: Really? With the parent element set to `position: relative`, it should be okay. The answer is UPDATED in the answer.

Comment: bit OK Shivan, Thnaks